# writing xlsx from raw byte corrupted

Tags: .net, excel, byte, xlsx

I have a client service which writes via a webservice to a varbinary(max) field in SQL.

I then write this via a response on a webpage to download via www.
This works fine for everything other than xlsx files.

I've tested without using the response and i have the same issue.

When opening Excel says 'we found a problem with some contents in..' attempt to open
Then 'Excel was able to open the file by repairing and removing...etc'

Client app reads via:

```
Dim objFileStream As IO.FileStream = New IO.FileStream(fileItem, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read)
Dim len As Integer = objFileStream.Length
Dim myByteArray(len) As Byte
objFileStream.Read(myByteArray, 0, len)
objFileStream.Close()
```

Then saves the myByteArray via the webservice.

Client writing extracts from db with entity framework and writes with :

```
System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(filePath1, output)
```

I've tried various methods to write the file but I consistently get this corruption message.

Any ideas?

edit:

If i remove the webservice / db transmission / storage etc I can narrow the problem down as follows:

-- read method:

```
Dim objFileStream As IO.FileStream = New IO.FileStream(fileItem, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read)
Dim len As Integer = objFileStream.Length
Dim myByteArray(len) As Byte
objFileStream.Read(myByteArray, 0, len)
objFileStream.Close()
```

-- immediate write:

```
System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes("c:\test.xlsx", myByteArray)
```

test.xlsx still presents the opening issues.

Comment: What header are you sending, and does it match the exact Excel file format ?  xls vs xlsx vs xlsb etc   Are you confident the stored version is not corrupted?

Comment: I'm not using any headers or any manipulation. I merely read into a byte array, save into a varbinary field, and write out. For a standard xls it works without any problems... and pdfs and html files. But xlsx gives me the corruption message

Comment: "I then write this via a response on a webpage to download via www." - you don't send any content-type headers?  if instead you write the content to a file on the server, is the file openable?

Comment: Edited question to make clearer

Comment: I don't have any suggestions.  What's the source of the xlsx files? Are you confident they're not *already* broken prior to being stored in the DB?  Can/have you compare the MD5 for source and extracted versions?

Comment: Yes no problems opening prior to the example.  I just create an xlsx.. save..  run that code the the result is different.  So there is no db interaction in this

Answer (score 1):

I did a raw file compare, as suggested and found that reading the xlsx into a byte array an additional null value was present at the final array point.

Redimensioning the array without the last item and then saving works perfectly.
db save load and subsequent response.writes also work well.

Thanks for your input